# CSS clip-path doesn't work in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, polygon, clip, clip-path

I have created a triangle watermark with CSS clip-path, but it's not rendered in Firefox. 
It works fine with Google Chrome.

Here is my css:

```
.displaywatermark2 {
-webkit-clip-path: url("#clip-shape");
clip-path: url("#clip-shape");
-webkit-clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 0% 100%, 100% 100%);
clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 0% 100%, 100% 100%);}
```

I've also added this code into my phtml:

```
<div class="displaywatermark2" id="<?php echo $block->getProduct()->getTypeId(); ?>watermark"></div>
        <svg class="clip-svg" width="0" height="0">

            <clipPath id="clip-shape" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
              <polygon points="0 100,100 100,100 100,0 0" />
            </clipPath>

        </svg>
```

Is this an known bug in Firefox or I have written something wrong into my code? Any other suggestion as alternative to create a triangle div?

Comment: Is your CSS in an external .css file ? Because this is a known **chrome** bug that it doesn't make the `#` document relative as it should.

Comment: yes, it is an external .less file; with chrome it works fine this kind of declaration: -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 0% 100%, 100% 100%);
 clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 0% 100%, 100% 100%); with Firefox it doesn't work.

Comment: Yes because `#id` is a document fragment identifier, so it means that FF tries to search for `yourFile.less#clip-shape` and obviously it doesn't find it. Chrome is the buggy one here, FF behavior is correct according to the specs and every other UAs. For a fix, you'll need to use an absolute path ( `url(yourFile.html#clip-path)`). Then everyone will be happy.

Comment: Thank you very much Kaiido!!!!! Now I'm happy and also Firefox is happy too :)